# Having trouble with findViewById in Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a for loop which is running through an an array of imageView ID's that correspond to imageViews in my 'Board' class. The code is below:

```
for (String s : chunks) {                                                   
    String possibleSquare = "s" + s.substring(2, 4);                        
    ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.possibleSquare);
    backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
```

I'm getting an error with findViewById and possibleSquare, specifically that Android 'cannot resolve' either.

Here is the xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/BoardHeading"
        android:text="Chessboard"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff2d3017"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/BoardHeading"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/s00"
            android:tag="black_rook"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F3E5AB"
            android:src="@drawable/black_rook"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/s01"
            android:tag="black_knight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#AF9B60"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/black_knight"
        />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/s02"
            android:tag="black_bishop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F3E5AB"
            android:src="@drawable/black_bishop"
            />
```

And there are 61 more imageViews similar to the ones above.

The exact error I'm getting for the findViewById is: 'Cannot resolve method findViewById(?)

The error for the possibleSquare variable is 'Cannot resolve symbol possibleSquare'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the exact error please.  But you have to have an id named possibleSquare in an xml file somewhere, or the system won't create the constant id and that won't be legal java.

Comment: Can you also post your xml file along with your error? Thank you.

Comment: well the issue is that I want to pass the dynamically generated name to the findviewbyid

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding how objects work in Java. `possibleSquare` is a very different thing semantically than `R.id.possibleSquare`. I'm assuming you've given your views IDs that look like `android:id="@+id/sSOMETHING"`

```
for (String s : chunks) {                                                   
    String possibleSquare = "s" + s.substring(2, 4);
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(possibleSquare, "id", getPackageName());                        
    ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
    backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));   
}
```

Note that if you're just looking to iterate over the `TableRow`, you could also do something like this:

```
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
int childCount  = tableRow.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
    ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) tableRow.getChildAt(i);
    backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way as R.id.possibleSquare is essentially  a variable name. It is not a string that you can use to replace content

You may want to look at this method

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(possibleSquare, "id", PACKAGENAME);
```

It will try to match the string to a resource ID. I used it to constract the ResID of a drawable. Never used it for ID but it may work for you